# Database driven Kendo Grid column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to enumerate the grid columns eg (title and width) coming from a database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make an ajax call for that. Derive the column names from the table and then you can make modifications.

For e.g.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:actionUrl, //Url of the Method for fetching names of the columns and its count
    success: function(result){
        for (var i = 0; i < result.columnsCount; i++) { //running the loop based on number of columns needed
            columns.push({ 
                field: result.columnName, //set the columnNames from the Db as field
                title: result.Header //specifying the columns title
            }); 
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: whoa thanks sir.. gonna try this one. i hope i could get this, im a newbie on mvc and kendo ui widgets.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var model = kendo.observable({
            gridRows: []
        });

    var columns = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var entryIndex = "entries[" + i + "]";
        columns.push({
            field: i,
            title: "Column " + i

        });
    }

    var configuration = {
        resizable: true,
        columns: columns
    };

    var timeEditGrid = $("#grid").kendoGrid(configuration).data("kendoGrid");


    kendo.bind($('#example'), model);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4sM7g/

Comment: Thanks!! is it possible that i will get the columns list from a table? kendo ui  has LoadColumnSettings functionality but it has been pass to a viewdata coming from array in the controller. Suggestions are well Appreciated.